# Dynamically generated slideshow bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, slide

I have a slideshow that takes image sources from JSON and generates a list for the amount of images . This is the code :

```
//Json
  var sidenav = $('.sidenav');

  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/data.json', function(result){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++) {
      sidenav.append(`<li class="selected"><img src="${result[i].src}" alt="${result[i].alt}"></li>`);

      var slides = $('.sidenav li');
      var slideIndex = 0;
      var slideTime = animate();

      slideTo(slides[0]);

      slides.click(function() {
      clearInterval(slideTime);
      slideTime = animate();

      var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
      var slide = slides[selectedIndex];
      slideTo(slide);

      });
    }

    function slideTo(slide) {
      slides.removeClass("selected");
      $(slide).addClass("selected");
      slideIndex = jQuery(slide).index();
    }

    function animate() {
      return setInterval(function() {
        var slide = slides[slideIndex];
        slideTo(slide)
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex == slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 0;
        }
      },3000);
    }

     <div class="slider">
        <ul class="sidenav">

        </ul>
      </div>
```

CSS is all over the place but not really important here . This works as it gets the first li item and adds a class `selected` . But than for some reason it jumps to the last one and doesn't move from there . I feel like I missed something small but important .. Any opinions ?

Answer (score 0):

OK the answer was to move the part where slides change out of the for loop..

```
var sidenav = $('.sidenav');

  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/data.json', function(result){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++) {
      sidenav.append(`<li class="selected"><img src="${result[i].src}" alt="${result[i].alt}"></li>`);
    }

    var slides = $('.sidenav li');
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var slideTime = animate();

    slideTo(slides[0]);

    slides.click(function() {
      clearInterval(slideTime);
      slideTime = animate();

      var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
      var slide = slides[selectedIndex];
      slideTo(slide);

      });

    function slideTo(slide) {
      slides.removeClass("selected");
      $(slide).addClass("selected");
      slideIndex = jQuery(slide).index();
    }

    function animate() {
      return setInterval(function() {
        var slide = slides[slideIndex];
        slideTo(slide)
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex == slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 0;
        }
      },3000);
    }
```